# Delete files containing string

Tags: powershell

How can I delete all files in a directory that contain a string using powershell?

I've tried something like

```
$list = get-childitem *.milk | select-string -pattern "fRating=2" | Format-Table Path
$list | foreach { rm $_.Path }
```

And that worked for some files but did not remove everything. I've tried other various things but nothing is working.

I can easily get the list of file names and can create an array with the path's only using

```
$lista = @(); foreach ($f in $list) { $lista += $f.Path; }
```

but can't seem to get any command (`del`, `rm`, or `Remove-Item`) to do anything. Just returns immediately without deleting the files or giving errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First we can simplify your code as:

```
Get-ChildItem "*.milk" | Select-String -Pattern "fRating=2" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty path | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm
```

The lack of action and errors might be addressable by one of two things. The `Force` parameter which:

> Allows the cmdlet to remove items that cannot otherwise be changed,
> such as hidden or read-only files or read-only aliases or variables.

I would aslo suggest that you run this script as administrator. Depending where these files are located you might not have permissions. If this is not the case or does not work please include the error you are getting.

Im going to guess the error is:

```
remove-item : Cannot remove item C:\temp\somefile.txt: The process cannot access the file 'C:\temp\somefile.txt'
because it is being used by another process.
```

**Update**

In testing, I was also getting a similar error. Upon research it looks like the Select-String cmd-let was holding onto the file preventing its deletion. Assumption based on i have never seen Get-ChildItem do this before. The solution in that case would be encase the first part of this in parentheses as a sub expression so it would process all the files before going through the pipe.

```
(Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "tes" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty path) | Remove-Item -Force -Confirm
```

Remove `-Confirm` if deemed required. It exists as a precaution so that you don't open up a new powershell in `c:\windows\system32` and copy paste a remove-item cmdlet in there.

**Another Update**

`[` and `]` are wildcard searches in powershell in order to escape those in some cmdlets you use `-Literalpath`. Also `Select-String` can return multiple hits in files so we should use `-Unique`

```
(Get-ChildItem *.milk | Select-String -Pattern "fRating=2" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty path -Unique) | ForEach-Object{Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $_}
```

Comment: If I do `(Get-ChildItem *.milk | Select-String -Pattern "fRating=2" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty path) | Remove-Item -Force` I get an error `Remove-Item : The specified wildcard pattern is not valid: Flexi - area 51 [reaction-diffusion on lotka-volterra
vertex warp, alien edge glow kaleidoscope.milk
At line:1 char:93
+ ... operty path) | Remove-Item -Force
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], WildcardPatternException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand`

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with quotes or what. I think maybe the `[` and `]` in the file name to cause powershell to crap out?

Comment: I am updating my post

Comment: Thanks. Had to remove Unique(got error) but seems to be working now. Is there any way to count how many files were found and how many were actually deleted and report that at the end? (also, for bonus points, I need to actually delete all files with `fRating <= 2`. I'm running the command for each rating(0,1,2) now... but rather do a comparison

Comment: The unique was supposed to be part of `select-object` not `select-string` i updated my post.

Comment: If you were do `Get-ChildItem *.milk | Measure-Object` before and after the removes that would tell you the difference. Also you can change your pattern to `fRating=[01]` that will match `=0` or `=1`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `select-string -pattern "fRating=2"`? You would like to select all files with this name?
I think the `Format-Table Path` don't work. The command `Get-ChildItem` don't have a property called "Path".
Work this snipped for you?

```
$list = get-childitem *.milk | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -match "fRating=2"}
$list | foreach { rm $_.FullName }
```

Comment: The OP is looking for files where their content contains the line "fRating=2". The output of `select-string` has a path property. This also does not address the actual issue of deleting the files.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gets all files of type *.milk and puts them in `$listA`, then uses that list to get all the files that contain the string `fRating=[01]` and stores them in `$listB`. The files in `$listB` are deleted and then the number of files deleted versus the number of files that contained the match is displayed(they should be equal).

```
sv -name listA -value (Get-ChildItem *.milk); sv -name listB -value ($listA | Select-String -Pattern "fRating=[01]"); (($listB | Select-Object -ExpandProperty path) | ForEach-Object {Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $_}); (sv -name FCount -value ((Get-ChildItem *.milk).Count)); Write-Host -NoNewline Files Deleted ($listA.Count - $FCount)/($listB.Count)`n;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate things:

`1. $sourcePath = "\\path\to\the\file\"

 2. Remove-Item "$sourcePath*whatever*"`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question, he wants to remove a file that contains a certain string inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer, unfortunately, errors seems to always come up, however, I managed to create a solution to get this done:

Without using Get-ChilItem; You can use select-string directly to search for files matching a certain string, yes, this will return the filename:count:content ... etc, but, internally these have names that you can chose or omit, the one you need is the "filename" to do this pipe this into "select-object" choosing the "FileName" from the output.

So, to select all *.MSG files that has the pattern of "Subject: Webservices restarted", you can do the following:

> Select-String -Path .*.MSG -Pattern 'Subject: WebServices Restarted'
>   -List | select-object Filename

Also, to remove these files on the fly, you could pip into a ForEach statement with the RM command as follows:

> Select-String -Path .*.MSG -Pattern 'Subject: WebServices Restarted'
>   -List | select-object Filename | foreach { rm $_.FileName }

I tried this myself, works 100%.

I hope this helps